# sqlite update field in row not recognizing variable for row id

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

My first time attempt to update a field in record, but, its not saving update when using a variable to specify the row.

Issue background - When the user clicks on an image, the checkDone() function is called, passing the row number (i).  I then set a global variable (glbID) to the row nbr (i), and called the updateDB function to update the status field for the specified row.  I never received an error, but, noticed the field was not updating.  When I hardcoded the row id it saved the update.  But, using the glbID var, as well as another strID to see if it was a format type issue, could not resolve the issue.  Have tried several other variations to no avail.

Appreciate any one’s help on this.  Am testing with Android emulator, let me know if any other info helpful for analysis.

```
function checkDone(i) {
   var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "GTKdb", 200000);
   glbID = i    //SET global variable to row nbr
   document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].src = "img/checkbox_checked.png";
   db.transaction(updateDB, errorCB); 
}


function updateDB(u) {        
   var strDone = "DONE"
    var strID = "" + glbID;  //SET new variable to glbID, converting to string to see if format type issue

    u.executeSql('UPDATE USER set status = ? where id = ?', [strDone,"2"], successCB, errorCB); //THIS WORKS WHEN ID value hardcoded
   //u.executeSql('UPDATE USER set status = ? where id = ?', [strDone,glbID], successCB, errorCB); //NO UPDATE using var glbID
   //u.executeSql('UPDATE USER set status = ? where id = ?', strDone,strID], successCB, errorCB); //NO UPDATE using var strID
    alert('AFTER UPDATE Status= '+status);  //No value for status appears
}
```

Comment: Is the id field a string field? Thena you have place quotes around the number: Update USER set status = 'DONE' where id = '2'. Or is the id field an autoincrement field?

Comment: When I set up the input field, set type as number <input type="number" name="ID" id="ID" value="" />.  Not sure if that changes after, or how to check how its stored in the database.  Am a total beginner.

Comment: And I should clarify that it works fine when I have the id value hardcoded with quotes, "2", in the update statment.  But, the problem is I need this to work with a variable since the row ID will vary based on user clicking on different rows...

Comment: Did you try pushing glbID to logcat to see if it was ok? Or just printing it somewhere? I'm not an Android developer, don't know what output you can get out of it.

Comment: I'm reading around on scope of "global" variables and callbacks and there appears to be something generally funky about them. How do you declare glblID?

Comment: Currently have it declared as var glbID = 0, and previously declared as = "0", null and other values to see if it was a format type issue.  No luck.  Also, have used alerts, and pushed to logcat as you suggested, and in both cases the glblID value before and after shows a value (0 before, and the row I selected 2 after).  But, after UPDATE the status does not show a value.

Comment: OK, I read somewhere that some global variables are hidden to callbacks for some reason. The [workaround](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?693917-Global-variable-not-valid-in-callback-function) is to define it in `window.Project`, it seems. Whatever `Project` is...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however, after attempting the workaround, I still experienced the same issue.  I added more alerts/logging details and found the global variable seemed to be passing in fine, then passed the global var internal to the function, but with the same amounts.  values and format types look good.  The ID  is just not being recognized within the Update statement itself.  Played around with the quotes, and finally got it to work with the following:  'UPDATE USER set status = ? where id = "'+nbrID+'"', [strDone],

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but this might be the problem. when you are inserting string you need to give it inside quotes.

```
'UPDATE USER set status = "?" where id = ?'
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks arthan, this was the correct path to resolution.  I didn't get it to work exactly by using the "?".  But, after a few variations and placing the var within the quotes, the following worked: 'UPDATE USER set status = ? where id = "'+nbrID+'"', [strDone],...